# How can I do a integration test to Spring OAuth 2.0 Provider developed?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I have 4 configurations files write in Java. These Java codes are based on the github 
Spring repository samples. I separeted the Resource and Authorization Configuration:

AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
    AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Value("${tonr.redirect:http://localhost:8080/tonr2/sparklr/redirect}")
private String tonrRedirectUri;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
        throws Exception {

    // @formatter:off
    clients.inMemory().withClient("tonr").resourceIds("resource01")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read", "write")
            .secret("secret");
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

}

I would like doing a test integration to test if the authorization is correct. For example, create a OAuthClient or something like that to test it but I don't have any idea to do that.